# How can i fetch multiple RSS feeds and merge them in one feed, then convert the merged feed to JSON data? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rss

I am trying to merge multiple RSS feeds into one and convert it to JSON. To merge the RSS feeds i used this package: [rss-combiner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-combiner)

Here is the code i used to merge the RSS feeds it works:

```
var RSSCombiner = require('rss-combiner');

var feedConfig = {
  title: 'Tech news from Guardian and BBC',
  size: 20,
  feeds: [
    'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml',
    'https://www.theguardian.com/uk/technology/rss'
  ],
  pubDate: new Date()
};

RSSCombiner(feedConfig)
.then(function (combinedFeed) {
  xml = combinedFeed.xml();
  console.log(xml);
});
```

Then to convert a feed to JSON i used this package: [rss-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-to-json) with this code and it works:

```
var Feed = require('rss-to-json');

Feed.load('https://codek.tv/feed/', function(err, rss){
   console.log(rss);
});
```

The problem is when i try to convert the merged feed to JSON, i don't get any results with this code:

```
var RSSCombiner = require('rss-combiner');
var Feed = require('rss-to-json');

var feedConfig = {
  title: 'Tech news from Guardian and BBC',
  size: 20,
  feeds: [
    'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml',
    'https://www.theguardian.com/uk/technology/rss'
  ],
  pubDate: new Date()
};

// combine feeds
RSSCombiner(feedConfig)
.then(function (combinedFeed) {
  var xml = combinedFeed.xml();

  // convert combined feed to json
  Feed.load(xml, function(err, rss){ 
    console.log(rss);
  });
});
```

Comment: Try logging `err` as well.

Comment: Still i get no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `rss-to-json` is asking for a URL; you're passing the XML result. Why not just use [`xml2js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) after you combining the RSS?

```
const RSSCombiner = require('rss-combiner');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');

const feedConfig = {
  title: 'Tech news from Guardian and BBC',
  size: 20,
  feeds: [
    'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml',
    'https://www.theguardian.com/uk/technology/rss',
  ],
  pubDate: new Date(),
};

RSSCombiner(feedConfig)
  .then((combinedFeed) => {
    const xml = combinedFeed.xml();
    const parser = xml2js.Parser();

    parser.parseString(xml, (err, result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  });
```

Comment: That worked! and i had to do this for it to display all the data: console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

Comment: My impression is this no longer works because result variable stores not the feed contents but ```{
  rss: {
    '$': {
      'xmlns:dc': 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/',
      'xmlns:content': 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/',
      'xmlns:atom': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom',
      version: '2.0'
    },
    channel: [ [Object] ]
  }
}```